# How I can give multiple input files to a perl script?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, bash, scripts

I am using a perl script to convert the file into json format.
Here is how the script is:

```
perl -MJSON -F, -lane '
    print to_json ({
           domain => shift @F,
           emails => [map {{email =>$_}} @F]
           }, {canonical=>1})
' input1.txt' > output.json
```

What I want to do is:  I want to give multiplt input files to the script or a complete folder containing the input files and and get one single output.
Say for example:

```
 perl -MJSON -F, -lane '
        print to_json ({
               domain => shift @F,
               emails => [map {{email =>$_}} @F]
               }, {canonical=>1})
    ' input1.txt','input2.txt','input3.txt' > output.json
```

### or

```
 perl -MJSON -F, -lane '
        print to_json ({
               domain => shift @F,
               emails => [map {{email =>$_}} @F]
               }, {canonical=>1})
    'path/to/inputfolder/containing/inputFiles' > output.json
```

How I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `for` loop:

```
for file in input{1..3}.txt; do
    perl -MJSON -F, -lane '
    print to_json ({
           domain => shift @F,
           emails => [map {{email =>$_}} @F]
           }, {canonical=>1})
    ' "$file" >> output.json
done
```

The first line could also be

```
for file in /path/to/inputfolder/containing/*; do
```

Assuming all the files in `containing` are input files you want to work on.

Don't forget to use `>> output.json` to append to the file, instead of `>`, or the file will get overwritten with each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Just for a small change. If I want the output in different files then what I can modify in the script? and also the process should run with very high priority.

Comment: to write out each file to a different file, you just need to give a new name for each, so you could replace `>> output.json` with `> $(basename "${f/.txt/.json}")` to create the files in the current working directory (while running the loop) or just `> "${f/.txt/.json}"` to create the files in the same directory as the input files. This will create a new file with the same name apart from replacing `.txt` with `.json` for each file. I don't know how to tell the process to run with high priority though @JafferWilson

Comment: @JafferWilson It's a pleasure as always :)

Comment: Zanna can we discuss some more problem in the chat room? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room